# Generic interface that returns nested object

Tags: typescript

```
interface User {
  data: {
    login: string;
  }
}
```

```
getData<T = any, K = keyof T>(data: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return data[key];
}
```

Expected behavior is that calling

```
const user: User = {
  data: {
    login: 'Daniel'
  }
}

getData(user, 'data');
```

would give me instant access to the `login` key. Instead I have warnings in return type but still the result of the function is correct. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=36&pln=16&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCIEMpYDwAqiAvIlmAJ4A0iA0iYgNaoVzCIEB8AFACY5YAXBxrMKw2gEphBANq0AuogDeAKESIATuhCak-XLLEKA3KoC%20q1TDBRUm4FgipEAVQDO9lesQGh3jQ0AGzhkG2F3KE0bZDMNS0tVCARIxBBPTWEPL1I1DT9hPMCQsLBhAHJsMBhUIPKfBKtksHc4INQAOhLuNEwBbnT7GnK-cslJEyA)

How to write the type for the function to make the typescript prompt correct keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not warnings, they are actual errors. `tsc` is telling you that `K` cannot be used to index `T`
(`Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.(2536)`).

You have to change you function signature so that `K` is correctly restricted to `keyof T`, like this

```js
function getData<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return data[key];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCIEMpYDwAqANIgNKKoAeUqYAJgM6IDWqAnnMIgQHwAUdHFgBc3EqzajSASlEEA2qQC6iAN4AoRIgBO6ENqSDc8iUoDc6gL7r1MMDW3AsEVIgCqDVNrWbERkT5aWgA2cMh2ogxQ2nbIFlrW1uoQCFGIIJ7aoh5eiAC8gX5CohpBiKHhYKIA5NhgMKjB1b6JNilgaVj5KOjYuHwZXiTV-tXS6lgAdBV2QA)

Comment: You may want to elaborate that the problem here is using [generic parameter *defaults*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) instead of [generic parameter *constraints*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  The former places no restrictions or guarantees on the type specified, while the latter does.